# Handling Automatic Retries in HTTP Requests due to HEAD and GET Discrepancies

Tags: angular, angularjs, spring, rest, haproxy

I've encountered a fascinating scenario in my application where the behavior of browsers and PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod seems to automatically reissue HTTP requests (both HEAD and GET) in response to metadata discrepancies. Interestingly, this behavior appears only for files around 120 MB in my location and around 60 MB in other location.

**Background:**

The application initially sends a HEAD request to fetch the file size, followed by a GET request for downloading.
However, if the size obtained from the HEAD request doesn't match the subsequent GET response, the client automatically restarts the download process.

**Observations:**

This behavior is consistent across different client environments (browsers and PowerShell) but varies based on the file size and geographical location.
The apparent re-issuing of requests seems to be initiated from the client side.

**Query:**

I'm seeking insights into potential mechanisms or configurations that could trigger this automatic re-issuing of requests, particularly the variations observed based on geographical location and file size. Could this behavior be influenced by network intermediaries such as HAProxy, or could it stem from client-side handling based on location or file size?

**Additional Information:**

The backend server doesn't seem to initiate request re-issuing based on metadata discrepancies.
I've examined client-side code but haven't found explicit retry logic based on metadata differences.
I'd greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or similar experiences in understanding what might be triggering this behavior, especially considering the geographic and file size-related variations. Thank you!